# LINQ: Select all from each group except the first item

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

It is easy to select the first of each group:

```
        var firstOfEachGroup = dbContext.Measurements
            .OrderByDescending(m => m.MeasurementId)
            .GroupBy(m => new { m.SomeColumn })
            .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
            .Select(g => g.First());
```

But...
**Question**: how can I select all from each group except the first item?

```
        var everythingButFirstOfEachGroup = dbContext.Measurements
            .OrderByDescending(m => m.MeasurementId)
            .GroupBy(m => new { m.SomeColumn })
            .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
            .Select( ...? );
```

Additional information:
My real goal is to delete all duplicates except the last (in a bulk way, ie: not using an in-memory foreach), so after the previous query I want to use `RemoveRange`:

```
 dbContext.Measurements.RemoveRange(everythingButFirstOfEachGroup);
```

So, if my **question** has no sense, this information might be handy.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `Skip(1)` to skip the first record and select the rest.

Something like:

```
var firstOfEachGroup = dbContext.Measurements
                    .OrderByDescending(m => m.MeasurementId)
                    .GroupBy(m => new { m.SomeColumn })
                    .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                    .SelectMany(g => g.OrderByDescending(r => r.SomeColumn).Skip(1));
```

See: [Enumerable.Skip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb358985%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

If you do not need a flattened collection then replace `SelectMany` with `Select` in code snippet.

Comment: Using `.Skip(1)` after `GroupBy(...)` will skip the first group, and that is not what I want. Oh, you edited your answer, now it makes sense

Comment: @sports, something like `.SelectMany(g => g.Skip(1));` after the where clause will give you what you need, I think. You will need `SelectMany` to flatten your collection.

Comment: This was needed too: `.SelectMany(g => g.OrderByDescending(r => r.SomeColumn).Skip(1));`

Comment: I thought so, Usually the collection should be ordered in some manner before applying `Skip`, or `Take`.

Comment: I accepted your answer, it solves my question. Although my original problem (bulk deleting duplicates) isnt resolved. The query is too slow :p (I think that sorting each group is the slow part). I'm gonna use straight SQL.

Comment: @sports, I must admit that I missed the part of deletion, But take a look at the generated SQL, It might give you a hint for why it is slow.

Answer (score 3):

`IGrouping<K, V>` implements `IEnumerable<V>`; you simply need to skip inside the select clause to apply it to each group:

```
.Select(g => g.Skip(1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use .Distinct() to remove duplicates; presumably sorting or reverse-sorting and then applying .distinct() would give you what you want.